# how to get mac address from ip address from client site in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i want to store details of visitor in site like
ip and mac address

i got ip address of client
but how can i get mca address of client ?

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: you can't. The MAC address is never transmitted. The best you can hope is to get the IP but remember that this IP could be the one of a proxy server situated anywhere in the world if the user configured some proxy to access the internet.

Comment: so how can web check it that from where our site is hijack.. actually i am use this code to find who access my site from which location

Comment: @Bhargav Mistri, there is no reliable way. Remember that a user could even configure a proxy, so you might not even get the actual IP of the client but the one of the proxy.

Comment: The best you can do is get the IP address of the connection used to hijack, this could be used to geolocate where the connection came from, but this is not very accurate as ISPs tend to lease blocks of addresses.

Comment: @Bhargav Mistri, that question doesn't belong on StackOverflow. This is a programming related Q&A site.

Comment: Also, what Darin said. If I use an anonymous proxy to hijack your site, I might appear to be coming from Austria when I'm actually sitting in the UK.

Comment: @Bhargav Mistri, contact your ISP.

Comment: so my question is how FBI and others are trace you location ?

Comment: but how google and other show your location when you login ??

Comment: i notice that some sites are show data of your location when you open it

Comment: @Bhargav Mistri, they use the client IP. But as I said this is not reliable.

Comment: do you have any idea how can we get location from ip address ?

Comment: @Bhargav Mistri, yes there are online web services that you could query. Here's one example: http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Comment: @BhargavMistri die you find any soln...here i have got the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your website has been compromised you will have to contact the authorities in order to attempt to catch the person who did it.  In most countries regular citizens do not have the power or authority to request the type of information you need from ISPs.