# How to get MAC address of client machine?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get MAC address of client machine in c# and vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018982/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-machine-in-c-sharp-and-vb-net)

Below is my code which runs at server side:

```
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
    {
        IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
        string _temp = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_temp))
        {
            lblmac.Text = "your MAC address:<b> "+_temp+"</b>";
        }
    }
```

which gives the MAC(12 - digit hexadecimal number)address of server

I need to get mac address of the client machine.

How?

Comment: what is the client and the server in your context? is this app running on a machine of which you need the MAC or how is one machine connected/connecting to the other one?

Comment: Sorry to mention... through my web application :(

Comment: @AVD that's for client application!

Comment: you can not get the mac address of your clients, you can not even be sure about the ip.

Comment: @Shankar - Read this post - http://stackoverflow.com/q/5897816/142822

Comment: Is there any way to capture? i need to get this particular user has activated in x,y,z, machines... thanks for your valuable inputs

Comment: did you figured that out? if yes please share how you get the client's mac address, I need to do the same

Comment: @AliIssa Actually you can't. the best alternate soln is Silverlight Isolated storage, If your application is silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve the MAC address of a client machine visiting your web application. This information isn't even exposed to javascript for you to do the work on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done.

You could anyway work around the issue and make it so clients *tell* the server their own MAC address (you have the code already, should be easy).