# How to store an SDF file at client machine via web application?

Tags: web-applications, sql-server-ce, asp.net-4.0

I need your valuable inputs for my web application.

The thing is, I need to store an SDF database so that I can track the user in which machine he has activated the product. If a user activated a product on machine A, I have to store the product key on that machine.

If he tries to access it with another machine B, I need to block access to the program.

PS:

The reason I'm looking to store a DB at the client machine is a month ago [I tried to capture the MAC Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269140/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-machine), I didn't get any solution.

Kindly give me your ideas for a solution to access local DB or get client machine MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an entire database to store a single license key - in addition, unless the user  has plugins/addons, there's no way of storing arbitrary information on the client PC via a web browser (at least not until HTML5 is more widely adopted).

Flash can do this, as could Google's Gears and various similar plugins - but not natively.

Also, what's to stop the user transferring the key from one machine to another?

You'd be better off taking a "fingerprinting" approach - gather some unique information about the machine, hash it and store the hash beside the license info in YOUR database. That way when a client connects, you can check the ahsh is correct before allowing access.

The tricky bit is what to hash and how to get it - You need to pick something you can access easily, is VERY unlikely to change and is PC- not User- specific.

Don't forget that ANY information from a client PC should be treated as suspect/malicious. Relying on the client to send you a product key every time would only need a single proxy/packet sniffer to allow someone on a different machine to fake it.

The short answer is, this can't be done reliably and robustly - if it could, there wouldn't be any software piracy. Whatever approach you come up with should rely entirely on server-side decisions and you want to make it as complex as possible to intercept the authentication messages (SSL at the *very least*).

One final point - pretend every client PC is a malicious hacker - if the hacker knows the product key, they can replicate it - so don't give them the key, give them a random hash that, when looked up inside your system finds the key. That way, you can disable/refresh hashes if they're compromised without having to change the underlying product key

Comment: Thanks for you reply...i have tried with HTML5 but IE is slight incompatible not as like chrome... so still searching for the right soln... Thanks and well said.